# JavaScript init + html5 tag

Tags: javascript, menu, slider, init

I have menu code with JS slider:

In HTML:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    menuSlider.init('nav', 'slide');
}

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li value="1"><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="slide"></div>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
var menuSlider=function(){
    var m,e,g,s,q,i; e=[]; q=8; i=8;
return{
    init:function(j,k){
        m=document.getElementById(j); e=m.getElementsByTagName('li');
        var i,l,w,p; i=0; l=e.length;
        for(i;i<l;i++){
            var c,v; c=e[i]; v=c.value; if(v==1){s=c; w=c.offsetWidth; p=c.offsetLeft}
            c.onmouseover=function(){menuSlider.mo(this)}; c.onmouseout=function(){menuSlider.mo(s)};
        }
        g=document.getElementById(k); g.style.width=w+'px'; g.style.left=p+'px';
    },
    mo:function(d){
        clearInterval(m.tm);
        var el,ew; el=parseInt(d.offsetLeft); ew=parseInt(d.offsetWidth);
        m.tm=setInterval(function(){menuSlider.mv(el,ew)},i);
    },
    mv:function(el,ew){
        var l,w; l=parseInt(g.offsetLeft); w=parseInt(g.offsetWidth);
        if(l!=el||w!=ew){
            if(l!=el){var ld,lr,li; ld=(l>el)?-1:1; lr=Math.abs(el-l); li=(lr<q)?ld*lr:ld*q; g.style.left=(l+li)+'px'}
            if(w!=ew){var wd,wr,wi; wd=(w>ew)?-1:1; wr=Math.abs(ew-w); wi=(wr<q)?wd*wr:wd*q; g.style.width=(w+wi)+'px'}
        }else{clearInterval(m.tm)}
}};}();
```

In orginal code there was a `<ul class="menu">` and `menuSlider.init('menu', 'slide');` My question is how to init this script with just `'nav'` tag? I wouldn't like to have this menu class in my `ul` tag. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it would work if you changed line 5:

```
m=document.getElementById(j); e=m.getElementsByTagName('li');

//                          your preferred element here  |
//                                                       V
m=document.getElementById(j); e=m.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Then update your HTML and CSS accordingly...

```
<div id="nav">
  <div>Item One</div>
  <div>Item Two</div>
  <div>etc.    </div>
</div>
```

---

update: what about...

```
m=document.getElementsByTagName(j)[0]; e=m.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Comment: But I would like to stay 'ul' and 'li' but init this script via 'nav' tag without any class or id

Comment: @Krzy Oh, sorry I get you now - updated.  Basically if you `init('nav', 'slide')` that will grab the first element only.

Comment: I have now: 'menuSlider.init('menu', 'slide')' and '<nav><ul id="menu"><li><a>Link</a></li></ul></nav> How to get this ul without class or id?

Comment: @Krzy that last line above should do it without classes or IDs as far as I can see?  (assuming the rest of the script is correct).